# How to overcome "server refused our key"?

Tags: unix, ssh, putty

I am trying to setup putty for autologin using public key authentication (used puttygen). I have pasetd my private key in authorized_keys ,I have done all the required setups still I am getting "server refused our key".What could be the reason behind it and how to overcome this issue ?

Comment: For example, if the authorized_keys file is group or world writable, it won't work.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it doesn't concern programming. That said, you have to out your public key into the `authorized_key` file.

Answer (score 4):

Run these commands:

```
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
chown $USER:$USER .ssh -R
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cd  /.ssh
```

If it doesnt exist create it in your home directory

```
mkdir .ssh
```

add your key with this command

```
echo "your_key" >> authorized_keys
```

[image]

Comment: I am done with these steps , but when I try to login .... I am getting  "server refused our key".Do you have solution for this issue ?

Comment: @RahSin it means your public does not match the private , my advice is to do it over as its quick to set up, you missed something

Answer (score 0):

run these commands where can't even get in
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
chown $USER:$USER .ssh -R

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo chown root:root /home
$ sudo chmod 755 /home
$ sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user -R
$ sudo chmod 700 /home/ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh
$ sudo chmod 600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```